# {multicol} vs. \documentclass[twocolumn]{book}

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicol, books

I've looked and tested various codes, but I'm afraid I can't figure this one out: how to center within the page the document's title, TOC, LOT, Preamble, and Intro, and whatever portion of text I'd like to center?

The document uses the `/multicol` package, so it should be possible, on a case to case basis, to make certain elements of the formatting appear right in the center of the page (not the center of the body of text).

What am I doing wrong?

```
%preamble
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {h:/} }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\setlength{\columnsep}{8mm}

%Table of Content depth
\geometry{verbose}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%Hyperlinks for TOC
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\makeatother

%Formating Document per Pto-M-cook
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={21.59cm,27.94cm},
    top=2.8cm,
    bottom=2.1cm,
    inner=1.91cm,
    outer=6.68cm,
    marginparwidth=4cm,
    marginparsep=0.8cm
}

%\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil \Huge}

\begin{document}

\title{A Fantastic Title}
\author{Author's Name}

\maketitle

%To clear empty page before TOC
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\section*{Preamble}
\lipsum[75]

\section*{Introduction}
\lipsum[75]

%To clear empty page before Chapter
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Following is the code used to create vertical bars between text body and margin

\def\bottommargin{\paperheight - \topmargin - \textheight - \headheight - \headsep - 1in - \voffset}
\def\toptotalheight{\paperheight - \topmargin - \headheight - \headsep - 1in - \voffset}
\def\leftlength{
    \evensidemargin - 0.5*\marginparsep
    + 1in
    + \hoffset
}
\def\rightlength{\paperwidth
    - \evensidemargin + 0.5*\marginparsep
    - 1in - \hoffset}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nomarginbar}{\let\ESO@HookIIBG\@empty}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\thisisfullsize}{\path (0,0) --  (\paperwidth,\paperheight);}

\newcommand\LeftBar{%
    \put(0,0){%
        \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
            \vfill
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \thisisfullsize
            \draw[line width=0.4pt] (\leftlength,\bottommargin) -- (\leftlength,\toptotalheight);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \vfill
}}}

\newcommand\RightBar{% 
    \put(0,0){%
        \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
            \vfill
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \thisisfullsize
            \draw[line width=0.4pt] (\rightlength,\bottommargin) -- (\rightlength,\toptotalheight);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \vfill
}}}

%%% Use this in two-side documents
\AtBeginShipout{%
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
    {\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\LeftBar}%
    }%
    {\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\RightBar}%
    }%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter{The First Chapter}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\section{The First Proper Section}
\lipsum[75]

And now this table:

\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{r|c|c|l}
    \hline
    Information & Information & Information & Information\tabularnewline \hline  Information & Information & Information & Information\tabularnewline Information & Information & Information & Information\tabularnewline Information & Information & Information & Information\tabularnewline Information & Information & Information & Information\tabularnewline Information & Information & Information & Information\tabularnewline
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Important Data}
\end{table*}

\marginnote{\lipsum[75]}[3cm]

\lipsum[75]

\subsection{The Subsection}
\lipsum[75]

And now I'm going to list a list of listed things:
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
    \item \lipsum[75]
    \item \lipsum[75]
    \item \lipsum[75]
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[75]

\subsubsection{A Subsubsection}
\lipsum[75]

\marginnote{\lipsum[75]}[3cm]

\lipsum[75]

%To clear empty page before Chapter
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\chapter{The Second Chapter}

\section{The Second Proper Section}
\lipsum[75]

The image should appear right after this:

%\includegraphics*{universe}

And now, more text to see how this works.

\subsection{The Second Subsection}
\lipsum[75]

\subsubsection{A Second Subsubsection}
\lipsum[75]

\marginnote{\lipsum[75]}[3cm]

\lipsum[75]

\end{multicols*}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: why the `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` (certainly why the second and third ones  which obviously do nothing)

Comment: you have posted a very long example but it isn't clear what  you want to change. Is it just the front matter?

Comment: It's the front matter right now, but I have a feeling the same technique could be applied to also center the chapter headers.

Comment: Also, thanks for the heads up on the cleardoublepage issue. Didn't realize I only had to insert it once for the entire document.

Comment: inserting it at all is very odd, what is the intention? (the code does not fit the comment that is on the line above) the `\et` doesn't actually do anything at that point it just redefines (breaks) `\cleardoublepage`  but repeatedly defining to the same definition so does nothing after the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I can tell, you are looking for something like

[image]

```
%preamble
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {h:/} }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\setlength{\columnsep}{8mm}

%Table of Content depth
\geometry{verbose}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%Hyperlinks for TOC
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\makeatother

%Formating Document per Pto-M-cook
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={21.59cm,27.94cm},
    top=2.8cm,
    bottom=2.1cm,
    inner=1.91cm,
    outer=6.68cm,
    marginparwidth=4cm,
    marginparsep=0.8cm
}

%\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil \Huge}

\begin{document}

\title{A Fantastic Title}
\author{Author's Name}

\begingroup


\oddsidemargin=0.5\dimexpr\paperwidth-\textwidth-2in\relax
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\maketitle

%To clear empty page before TOC ???????!!
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\section*{Preamble}
\lipsum[75]

\section*{Introduction}
\lipsum[75]

\clearpage
\endgroup
\clearpage

%To clear empty page before chapter ???????!!
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Following is the code used to create vertical bars between text body and margin

\def\bottommargin{\paperheight - \topmargin - \textheight - \headheight - \headsep - 1in - \voffset}
\def\toptotalheight{\paperheight - \topmargin - \headheight - \headsep - 1in - \voffset}
\def\leftlength{
    \evensidemargin - 0.5*\marginparsep
    + 1in
    + \hoffset
}
\def\rightlength{\paperwidth
    - \evensidemargin + 0.5*\marginparsep
    - 1in - \hoffset}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nomarginbar}{\let\ESO@HookIIBG\@empty}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\thisisfullsize}{\path (0,0) --  (\paperwidth,\paperheight);}

\newcommand\LeftBar{%
    \put(0,0){%
        \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
            \vfill
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \thisisfullsize
            \draw[line width=0.4pt] (\leftlength,\bottommargin) -- (\leftlength,\toptotalheight);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \vfill
}}}

\newcommand\RightBar{% 
    \put(0,0){%
        \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
            \vfill
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \thisisfullsize
            \draw[line width=0.4pt] (\rightlength,\bottommargin) -- (\rightlength,\toptotalheight);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \vfill
}}}

%%% Use this in two-side documents
\AtBeginShipout{%
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
    {\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\LeftBar}%
    }%
    {\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\RightBar}%
    }%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter{The First Chapter}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\section{The First Proper Section}
\lipsum[75]

And now this table:

\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{r|c|c|l}
    \hline
    Information & Information & Information & Information\tabularnewline \hline  Information & Information & Information & Information\tabularnewline Information & Information & Information & Information\tabularnewline Information & Information & Information & Information\tabularnewline Information & Information & Information & Information\tabularnewline Information & Information & Information & Information\tabularnewline
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Important Data}
\end{table*}

\marginnote{\lipsum[75]}[3cm]

\lipsum[75]

\subsection{The Subsection}
\lipsum[75]

And now I'm going to list a list of listed things:
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
    \item \lipsum[75]
    \item \lipsum[75]
    \item \lipsum[75]
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[75]

\subsubsection{A Subsubsection}
\lipsum[75]

\marginnote{\lipsum[75]}[3cm]

\lipsum[75]

%To clear empty page before chapter ???????!!
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\chapter{The Second Chapter}

\section{The Second Proper Section}
\lipsum[75]

The image should appear right after this:

%\includegraphics*{universe}

And now, more text to see how this works.

\subsection{The Second Subsection}
\lipsum[75]

\subsubsection{A Second Subsubsection}
\lipsum[75]

\marginnote{\lipsum[75]}[3cm]

\lipsum[75]

\end{multicols*}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works super well, David. Thank you. Didn't think of using \begingroup. I'm puzzled though: although the \begingroup + \endgroup commands are circumscribed to the section of the document I was hoping to fix, the vertical line that used to appear on the Chapter1 page now only starts a page later. Is that group having an averse impact on those lines?

Comment: possibly, you may want to not have the final clearpage within the group, I didn't check exactly what you were doing there (@nofare)

Comment: I tried that, to no avail. Seems that the group's formatting coordinates are impacting the document beyond the \endgroup command, which is puzzling. Gonna have to find another way to include those vertical rules. I wasn't super happy about the vertical rule code anyway: very heavy.